# python updating and deleting data

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open(test , 'a')   
file.write(str(name + " : " )) 
file.write(str(score))
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

my txt file look like this:

```
helen:0
helen:4
jyp:7
helen:6
helen:8
john:7
helen:9
```

how do I print out the latest 3 scores of (Helen) and how do I delete the old scores?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is reccomended that you show what you have tried so far and what specific problem you are running into. See the asking questions section or the site tour.https://stackoverflow.com/tour. That being said, you will also want to use .read() to read in the data. You can loop over the line read in and use methods for strings to help you in finding helen(I would reccomend find() and/or index()). See the documentation here.https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html